# Pre processor commands, elif debuglive not being hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am using some preprocessor commands in my project so that I can specify a connection string.  Basically it's:

```
#if DEBUG
    return @"Network connection 1"
#elif DEBUGLIVE
    return @"Network connection 2"
#else
   return @"Default connection"
#endif
```

However, though I am setting the solution in VS 2008 to Debuglive it is in fact passing back the dubug connection string, why is that?

Edit:

Ok, so I have not used the preprocessor commands before and I am not sure how they work.  I am also working on projects which have been written by other people so I didn't know 'DEBUGLIVE' is something you have to create.  So, my question is now, as I can't work it out from the other projects, how do you set up within your project settings 'DEBUGLIVE'?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't let us repro this issue.  You have to improve it.

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but what about adding semicolons to the end of your return lines?

Comment: have you had a chance to try my answer?  I'm pretty sure it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the project and go to `Properties` from there go in Build.  There should be a build called "Conditional compilation symbols".

You can add DEBUGLIVE to that list.  You have set different symbols for different configurations, and they don't need to be the same name as the configuration (though it does make things easier to remember)

You'll notice underneath "Conditional compilation symbols" there's a checkbox for Define DEBUG constant.  That's why the DEBUG one is getting hit because that is checked for default in a Debug configuration.  As far as I know, it's simply a shortcut for typing DEBUG in the box above, and it would be functionally equivalent if you unchecked that box and typed DEBUG in the list of symbols.

Comment: Nope, still goes for the debug.

Comment: I am working on projects created by other programmers and I didn't know debuglive wasn't part of the default setup, it's always been there and I have never used it till now, so I need to know how to set it it up as the msdn is actually pretty unhelpful.

Comment: @flav Sorry, I kinda changed my answer completely based on your updates and some playing around.  That should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your solution configuration also sets the project configuration appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is now, as I can't
>   work it out from the other projects,
>   how do you set up within your project
>   settings 'DEBUGLIVE'?

```
#define DEBUGLIVE
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it's kinda hard-coded so you'll need to change the source code file in order to change configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I was undergoing the same thing. The easiest way is to do like Davy8. In addition you will have to add a new build in the configuration manager. Just click the drop down under the Debug tab in VS 2017 and select configuration manager and in that select Add. Then you can name your DEBUGLVE and save. Also you have to specify  in the web.config